# Return results in join even when condition is not true

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

final query :

```
SELECT b.id, a.T1 FROM (query1) AS a JOIN (query2) AS b ON a.id = b.id
```

the query1 and 2 brings numbers when a date match, but when the date don't match (query2 = empty set) the other one fails too , I'll need to put a zero if one is empty.

my attempt to solve it with an IF faild, if the date exist works fine, but if don't returns empty set.

```
SELECT 
admin,
       IF(COUNT(date)=NULL,0,SUM(1P)) AS 1P
FROM carga 
WHERE date ="2014-08-14" 
GROUP BY admin;
```

any idea will be welcome, thanks

Comment: Maybe `LEFT JOIN` ? //pseudo code in the question is not very clear

Comment: JOIN as you have written here translates to 'Inner join'.  Inner join drops rows where the corresponding row isn't found.  Left Join (left outer join) will return nulls when the row is not found instead of dropping the row

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The connection between the two queries you have is so subtle that it eludes me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT b.id, a.T1
FROM (query1) AS a
LEFT JOIN (query2) AS b ON a.id = b.id
```

`LEFT JOIN` means that the result should include all rows from the first table.
If there's no match in the second table, all those columns (e.g. `b.id`) will be `NULL` in the result, but it will still show the columns from the first table.

You can slao use `RIGHT JOIN`, which reverses the roles of the first and second tables.